# How can I set up DNS for Bonjour and AirPrint to advertise printers across subnets

Tags: printing, dns, services, airprint, cups

Several printers do not stay connected to clients--even though everything has static ip addresses--and they are not searchable across networks i.e. they do not appear with Bonjour.

Ideally I would like to setup DNS so that in all of my networks, printers could just be added with Bonjour, and then as well, the settings would continue to work the next day, assuming the IP addresses, etc. did not change.

Apple says very clearly [at the top, here](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201311) to "use DNS to print across networks," but unfortunately does not explain how to do this!  I suspect that gesture was aimed at converging Windows users.

All the resources I find online, seem quite old--for example, [here is information that was really exciting](https://sites.google.com/site/iwastepaper/), and [from Apple, all 3 printers are listed here](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201311)--but in the OSX Server interface, or the latest OSX, there is not even a way to add many of the services people describe.

To be specific; these are all HP Printers, [which support Airprint](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201311), and the server is running Yosemite with 5.0.1 (the same problem existed on server 4 as well), with the clients either on Yosemite or 10.11.

The firewall settings for layer 2, 3, and 7 are all correct and not interfering with this, as far as I know (have experimented, with it off).  Also I have experimented with enabling and disabling IPv6.

Answer (score 3):

I have solved this problem by allowing a selected group of the guests to be on the same LAN as the printers; however blocking them significantly with firewalls so that only the printers and a few other machines needed, can be reached from that specific wi-fi network.

*If you see that I have provided this answer to my own question;  I'd **still love to hear how to configure DNS for Bonjour** in the current versions of OSX and Server, and otherwise forward Airprint or other protocols as examples.*

Answer (score 2):

You need to study and research an internet standard (described in [RFC-6763](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc6763.txt)) called *"DNS Service Discovery"*, short: DNS-SD.

All further info you need for that is hosted on [DNS-SD.org](http://dns-sd.org) and on [ZeroConf.org](http://www.zeroconf.org/).

There, have a look at ["How to set up Wide-Area AirPrint"](http://www.dns-sd.org/ServerStaticSetup.html#AirPrint). Draw your conclusions about how to achieve the same with AirPlay. (Hint: the DNS service records are differently named...)